# Program not compiling after casting pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main (void) {

  struct addrinfo hints; 
  memset (&hints, 0, sizeof hints);

  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; 
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;  
  hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;   

  struct addrinfo *res;

  getaddrinfo ("example.com", "http", &hints, &res);
  printf ("Host: %s\n", "example.com");

  void *ptr;

  while (res != NULL) {

    printf("AI Family for current addrinfo: %i\n", res->ai_family);

    switch (res->ai_family) {
      case AF_INET:
        struct sockaddr_in *sockAddrIn = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr;
        printf("Port number: %u\n", ntohs(sockAddrIn->sin_port));
        printf("IP address is: %u\n", ntohs(sockAddrIn->sin_addr.s_addr));
        break;
    }
    res = res->ai_next;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And in action:

> $ gcc ex3.c
>   $ ./a.out
>   Host: example.com
>  AI Family for current addrinfo: 2
>  Port number: 80
>  IP address is: 23992
>  AI Family for current
>   addrinfo: 30

This is all fine, however this does not even compile:

```
void *ptr;

while (res != NULL) {

printf("AI Family for current addrinfo: %i\n", res->ai_family);

switch (res->ai_family) {
  case AF_INET:
    ptr = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr;
    printf("Port number: %u\n", ntohs(ptr->sin_port));
    printf("IP address is: %u\n", ntohs(ptr->sin_addr.s_addr));
    break;
}
res = res->ai_next;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to cast a `void` pointer to a `struct sockaddr_in *`. The compile error is:

> ex3.c:33:48: error: member reference base type 'void' is not a
>   structure or union
>
> ```
> printf("IP address is: %u\n", ntohs(ptr->sin_addr.s_addr));
> ```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the pointer `ptr` not casted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
ptr = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr;
```

does not do what you think it does; it doesn't automagically make `ptr` be of type `struct sockaddr_in *`, so you're still trying to dereference a `void` pointer. What you need to do is

```
printf("Port number: %u\n", ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr)->sin_port));
```

Comment: Just one more question if I may. Why is this printf("IP address is: %u\n", ntohs(sockAddrIn->sin_addr.s_addr)); still printing 23992? I was hoping to get something like 120.32.3.2 ..

Comment: @KorayTugay Two problems - first, `ntohs` stands for `network to host short` - short meaning two bytes, as is the case with ports. You want `ntohl`. Second, IPv4 addresses are in fact 32 bit integers. To convert it to the decimal dot notation, which is what we're used to, you can use `inet_ntoa`, or better yet, `inet_ntop` (though the former has simpler syntax). Note that if you use these functions, you don't need to convert `sin_addr` to host byte order since they handle that for you.

Answer (score 4):

Type of `ptr` is `void *`, you need to add a cast to appropriate type before deferencing it.

Recall that: C does not allow dereferencing incomplete types. And `void` as per C specs is an incomplete type.

One simple fix is to change the type of ptr to `struct sockaddr_in *`.

You can also add cast in the `printf` line itself, but this will add unnecessary cluttering to the code.

Comment: Here is the cast: ptr = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr;

Comment: Yes, but the type of `ptr` remains `void`.

Comment: What does this code do then ptr = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr ?

Comment: @KorayTugay Change (reinterpret) `res->ai_addr` to(as) `struct sockaddr_in *` explicitly and then cast it implicitly to `void *` and assign it to ptr. Note that, **value** of variables may change in your program, but type does not.

Answer (score 2):

> *Why is the pointer ptr not casted?*

There is apparently no issue with the `cast`ing itself here. The problem is the usage of the `void` pointer `ptr` later in the code.

In your case, `ptr`  is a pointer to a `void` type. It does not have any *type* information, as compared to a `struct` pointer. Putting a pointer with `cast`ing into a `void *` variable does not change the type of the `void *` variable itself. It still remains an *incomplete type*, which cannot be used as an operand to *member (de)reference* operator.

In other words, a `void` type cannot have a *member*, so the *member reference* is outright wrong.

I don't see any use of making `ptr` a `void *`. Maybe , you want to define `ptr` as

```
 struct sockaddr_in * ptr = NULL;
```

to get around the issue.

That said, `%u` is not a format specifier to be used with a `uint16_t` type (return type of `ntohs()`). You may want to use `PRIu16` as the format specifier.

Comment: Here is the cast: ptr = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr;

Comment: @KorayTugay the _cast_ does not change the _type_ of `ptr`, does it? :-)

Comment: @KorayTugay Not much - assigns to value of `res->ai_addr` to `ptr`, but `ptr`'s _type_ remains the same.

Comment: @KorayTugay It tells  to _interpret_ the `res->ai_addr;` as a pointer to `struct sockaddr_in`, but `ptr` stays a `void *`.

Comment: But in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc one answer says: void * is automatically and safely promoted to any other pointer type.

Comment: @KorayTugay That's different - you're converting _from_ `void*` _to_ a  particular pointer type. In C, no force can change the type of a variable; once you make it a `void*`, it stays that way.

Comment: @szczurcio Ah I see, confusing, isn't it.. Thanks for the clarification. So a void* can not do much I assume?

Comment: `void*` is a very powerful concept in C, but you need to tell the compiler what to treat the data type as. When you do `ptr->sin_addr`, the compiler is confused. What's `sin_addr` in the context of `void*`? What is its size? Before you dereference a `void*`, it has to be cast to the right type so the compiler knows how to handle it.

Comment: @szczurcio ok thanks a lot. I will do some more reading on this topic as I see that I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

Change the declaration of ptr from

```
void * ptr;
```

to

```
sockaddr_in* ptr;
```

Comment: This is not what I am asking.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like you are based on the code snippets.

Comment: Yes I am sure. See szczurcio 's answer if you like.

Comment: He said the same thing I did :-/

Comment: No he did not. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, but yes he did. You can cast `((sockaddr_in*)res->ai_addr)` inline like he suggested or you can assign it to ptr like I suggested: `sockaddr_in* ptr = (sockaddr_in*)res->ai_addr` it's the same thing. The point is that you can't do `void *ptr = (sockaddr_in*)res->ai_addr;`

Comment: Not anymore but I used to. See user3725297's answer for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

`ptr = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr`;

this is your error. ptr is a void pointer and you are going to assign a struct pointer to it. 
So you must first create a struct pointer and the assign the result from your cast to that.Do

```
struct sockaddr_in *ptr;
ptr = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr;
```